# Place control above Wpf Touch Keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard, touch

I am struggling to place my control above the touch keyboard.
Anyone has a thought of how to accomplish this?

Here is an example of the problem: http://screencast.com/t/kHqHy8PAq

I want to control to show above the keyboard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Input%20and%20Commands/TouchKeyboard/TouchKeyboardNotifier) on github.  It has the basic ways of connecting to the touch keyboard events and a basic decorator that can be used to shift controls in response to them.  You can modify them or use the ideas as you see fit to best suit your application.